# How to display image in angular ngFor from object url?

Tags: angular

```js
for (let i = 0; i < newsValues.length; i++) {
  this.newsX[newsValues[i]] = {
    title: newsValues[i].title,
    date: newsValues[i].published_on,
    url: newsValues[i].url,
    body: newsValues[i].body,
    image: newsValues[i].imageurl,
    tags: newsValues[i].tags
  };
}
```

Here I get the response, and I made my own object with properties I need, everything works except the image when I pass it through `*ngFor`.

this is my Html part:

```html
<nz-layout>
    <nz-content>
      <header>
        <h1>Cool Articles</h1>
      </header>
      <div class="band">
        <div class="item-7" *ngFor="let news of newsData">
          <a href="{{news.url}}" class="card">
            <div class="thumb" [style.background-image]="'url('+news.image+')'">
            </div>
            <article>
              <h1>{{news.title}}</h1>
              <span>Release Date: {{news.date | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd'}}</span>
            </article>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
   </nz-content>
</nz-layout>
```

Comment: must be work, see the value of news.images (if starts with a "/" or not, if is in the correct directory...

Comment: Goes like this 
Imageurl: "https://images.cryptocompare.com/news/default/ethereumworldnews.png"

Comment: I should suppose should be `[style.background-image]="'url(https://'+news.image+')'"`. Else Angular try to find your image in a directory images.cryptocompare.com/news/default

Comment: Angular looks the files according the `base href` tag. if we don't put a "/" before the image, e.g. `<img src="assets/images/imagen.jpg">` and base href is '/' and our app is in the directory c:/myapp, look for the file in `c:/myapp/assets/images/imagen.jpg`. In this case is equal use `/`assets/.... If your base href is another (imagine a multilanguage app where `base href="/es-ES"`, if we don't put the `/` search in c:/myapp/es-ES/assets/images/imagen.jpg

Answer (score 1):

- Check if 'news.image' value has http/https protocol. If not you might have to add it to the original array or in the template.

  ```
  image: newsValues[i].imageurl, //Check for http/https
  ```
- Make sure 'thumb' class has a height & width property attached to it.

Stackblitz - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ewpahe?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

why you are not using `img` tag?

```
<img [src]="news.image" ...../>
```

Comment: I tried that too, but only broken image thumbnail and empty div

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src = {{movie.Poster}} />
```

Works for me, after trial and error